# Is this LDAP filter valid syntax?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I'm configuring AD authentication for a product that wants to query AD for groups.  This query is finding nothing and the vendor has provided this

```
(objectClass=group)(objectClass=groupOfNames)(objectClass=groupOfUniqueNames)&(cn=*)((objectClass=group)(objectClass=groupOfNames)(objectClass=groupOfUniqueNames))
```

as the filter they're using to return the groups list.  I'm not an LDAP expert but this doesn't seem to fit the LDAP filter syntax I'm used to seeing (bracketed sets of 'attribute=value' with sets of () prefixed by & or |).  It's possible that this is an extract from a larger filter but it still doesn't look valid.  I've tried to test this using a script that I run LDAP queries using and I just get errors back.

Is this a valid LDAP query?

Comment: What are the specific errors that you get back from LDAP, when you use that filter in your script?

Comment: The vbs script I'm running returns SearchAD.vbs(90, 2) Provider: One or more errors occurred during processing of command.  I'm not sure if there's a way to return a more specific error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as I know it. As near as I can work out, it should be:

```
(&(cn=*)(|(objectClass=group)(objectClass=groupOfNames)(objectClass=groupOfUniqueNames)))
```

Comment: Since any object can only have one objectClass (as I understand AD) I think it would need to be (&(cn=*)(|(objectClass=group)(objectClass=groupOfNames)(objectClass=groupOfUniqueNames))) but that only returns me the built-in Microsoft groups ("Exchange Servers", for instance)

Comment: No, objects can have multiple objectClasses set. If you have a look at AD using an LDAP brower, and view the built-in Administrators group, you can see it has two objectClass attributes of top and group.  Computer accounts have top, person, organizationalPerson, user, and computer.  However, you are correct in that there should be an "or" in there; they probably are looking for anything in those three classes.  I've modified my answer accordingly; thanks for the catch.